# Unhide select menu when other select menu value is met - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I would like to show more select menus based on the option value selected. I tried doing this with jQuery but to no avail. Currently I hide the extra select menus with CSS and then would like to unhide a select menu based on the value that is set. Example, if 3 people are selected then three select menus will appear so then the user can set the age of the person.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/FnqF7/2/

jQuery:

```js
$('#numOfpeople').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 1) {
        $("#person1").show();
    }
    if ($(this).val() > 1) {
        $("#person2").show();
    }
    if ($(this).val() > 2) {
        $("#person3").show();
    }
    if ($(this).val() > 3) {
        $("#person4").show();
    }
    if ($(this).val() > 4) {
        $("#person4plus").show();
    }
});
```

```html
<div id="row">
    <label for="numOfpeople">Num of People:</label>
    <select name="people" id="numOfpeople">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="Person1" class="hide-row">
    <label for="people1">Person1:</label>
    <select name="people1" id="peoople">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="Person2" class="hide-row">
    <label for="people2">Person2:</label>
    <select name="people2" id="peoople">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="Person3" class="hide-row">
    <label for="people3">Person3:</label>
    <select name="people3" id="peoople">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="Person4" class="hide-row">
    <label for="people4">Person4:</label>
    <select name="people4" id="peoople">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div ID is with a capital P. In the jQuery you request it with a non-capital P.

That is why you never start with a capital ;)

Answer (score 0):

you have typo error,working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FnqF7/3/)

```
$("#person1").show();// you have small p
$("#Person1").show();//change to capital P
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#numOfpeople').change(function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(val > 0){
        if(val > 4){
            $("#person4plus").show();
        }        
        else{
            $("#Person"+val).show(); // made "p" capital
        }
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FnqF7/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Working Sample [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FnqF7/9/)

```
$('#numOfpeople').change(function () {
 var val = $(this).val();

 if (val > 0) {
    if (val > 4) {
        $("#person4plus").show();
    } else {
        var i;
        for (i = 1; i <= parseInt(val); i++) {
            $("#Person" + i).show();//make a p Capital
        }
    }}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

simple mistake which we usually do :)

```
$('#numOfpeople').change(function () {
if ($(this).val() == 1) {
    $("#Person1").show();
}
if ($(this).val() > 1) {
    $("#Person2").show();
}
if ($(this).val() > 2) {
    $("#Person3").show();
}
if ($(this).val() > 3) {
    $("#Person4").show();
}
if ($(this).val() > 4) {
    $("#Person4plus").show();
}
});
```